# RTF cell position tags

Tags: tags, position, cell, rtf, wordpad

Are there some cell position tag?
I see all ok with cells in wordpad but much worse/shifted in word.
I`d like to edit position  tags if they exists...[image]

Comment: It looks like there are two tables. Did you check all `\cellx` and their parameter values?

Comment: Yes there need to be two tables, it is made from database template written of RTF. I can`t understand these \cellx and their parameter values,  changing them has no affect at all...

Comment: Changing them has no affect when I open document in MS Word...

Answer (score 0):

I see this in docs

```
\cellxN Defines the right boundary of a table cell, including its half of the space between cells.
```

but editing this tag does not any effect to cell position...